# How to set DEFAULT ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + 5 MINUTES?

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table with three columns:

- "code" column (integers)
- two DATETIME columns ("created_at", "expires_at")

"created_at" column default value is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.

"expires_at" column default value is CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE.
So far no problem.

Now I would like the ON UPDATE values to be the same as the default ones:

- for the "created_at" column, ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP works like a charm.
- for the "expires_at" column, I can't get ON UPDATE (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)

The query to create the "expires_at" column

```
ALTER TABLE codes ADD expires_at DATETIME DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

work successfully.

When I try to add ON UPDATE,

```
ALTER TABLE codes ADD expires_at DATETIME DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE) ON UPDATE (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE);
```

this query doesn't work.

It returns the error: `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE)' at line 1`

I also tried with:

- NOW() instead of CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
- DATE_ADD() and ADDTIME() functions

but these solutions also do not work.

Comment: "does not work" does not tell us what went wrong. Please share the exact error message or describe the unexpected behaviour!

Comment: @Shadow Thanks for the advice, I've updated my post. This is my first question ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such expression in ON UPDATE is not allowed. You may use intermediate `updated_at` column and generated `expired_at` column.

### DEMO

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                      ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  expired_at DATETIME GENERATED ALWAYS AS (updated_at + INTERVAL 3 MINUTE)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1);
SELECT *, SLEEP(2) FROM test;
```

| id | created_at | updated_at | expired_at | SLEEP(2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-06 14:00:35 | 2023-01-06 14:00:35 | 2023-01-06 14:03:35 | 0 |

```
UPDATE test SET id = 2 WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM test;
```

| id | created_at | updated_at | expired_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2023-01-06 14:00:35 | 2023-01-06 14:00:37 | 2023-01-06 14:03:37 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/uGGVQXn2)